# Major NullPointerException crash surfacing

Tags: android, crash, admob

This crash just started appearing for hundreds of users on Nov 17 (it never appeared before that), across many versions of my app with many versions of AdMob with latest being `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0` and is now by far my biggest crash.

I use native and interstitial and App Open ads.

As anyone seen it or know anything about it? I can't reproduce it, user reports it happens after a couple seconds after app launch so it is when the library or a native, interstitial or App Open ad is loading.

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getWidth()' on a null object reference
  at aeh.c (aeh.java:5)
  at acv.h (acv.java:1)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.h (i.java:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.j.e (j.java:1)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.g.run (g.java)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: It seems to disappear on Nov 22. Maybe google fixes this crash.

Answer (score 1):

See the same in Crashlytics since Nov 17! Found only [this topic](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/ejJ81I2h2w8) on google groups

Comment: I’d post on the groups topic to say you have the same issue…that is monitored by Google and maybe the more reports of the same the more quickly they will fix it

Comment: Posted there about my case

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue almost across all my Apps. Admob version 20.5. regardless of SDK target the crash is gaining momentum. It seems like its due to the android external update in any of their Apis which is effecting other Apps

Comment: The issue was marked as resolved by Google on Monday or Tuesday, and I haven’t see any crashes since then.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).